# How can I remove "&amp;nbsp" from html contents?

Tags: python, html, string, unicode, beautifulsoup

I have a html page as:

```
<div class="theater">
    <div class="desc" id="theater_16109207495969942346">
        <h2 class="name"><a href="/movies?near=pune&amp;tid=df8f66de0a592b4a" id="link_1_theater_16109207495969942346">Esquare Victory Camp</a></h2>
        <div class="info">site no 2429,general thimayya road, camp contonment,oppositekayani bakery, Pune - 020 2613 2975
            <a class="fl" href="" target="_top"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showtimes">
        <div class="show_left">
            <div class="movie">
                <div class="name"><a href="/movies?near=pune&amp;mid=1cdcf90092189400">Hawaa Hawaai</a>
                </div><span class="info">Drama - Hindi</span>
                <div class="times"><span style="color:#666"><span style="padding:0 "></span>
                    <!-- -->10:30am</span><span style="color:#666"><span style="padding:0 "> &amp;nbsp</span>
                    <!-- -->3:45</span><span style="color:#666"><span style="padding:0 "> &amp;nbsp</span>
                    <!-- -->6:00</span><span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 "> &amp;nbsp</span>
                    <!-- -->8:30pm</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="show_right">
            <div class="movie">
                <div class="name"><a href="/movies?near=pune&amp;mid=6b59ad39004d895b">The Amazing Spider Man 2</a>
                </div><span class="info">Action/Adventure/Thriller - English - <a class="fl" href="/url?q=http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DSCjCk59PIzw&amp;sa=X&amp;oi=movies&amp;ii=0&amp;usg=AFQjCNGpVM5U04h0acABA7eApb6EIO4Ejw">Trailer</a></span>
                <div class="times"><span style="color:#666"><span style="padding:0 "></span>
                    <!-- -->1:00</span><span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 "> &amp;nbsp</span>
                    <!-- -->10:45pm</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where we can see we have `&amp;nbsp` at many places. There are many other unicode characters as well. I want to extract the contents of this page.
What I am doing is:

```
def removeNonAscii(s): return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)

myName = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "theater"})
for x in myName:
   xt = str(x)
   print removeNonAscii(xt)
   print "<br>"
```

The Result:

```
Esquare Victory Camp
site no 2429,general thimayya road, camp contonment,oppositekayani bakery, Pune - 020 2613 2975
Hawaa Hawaai
Drama - Hindi
10:30am &nbsp3:45 &nbsp6:00 &nbsp8:30pm
The Amazing Spider Man 2
Action/Adventure/Thriller - English - Trailer
1:00 &nbsp10:45pm
```

Everything looks good except `&nbsp` . I tried replacing &nbsp, and searched for other solutions too but still have no solution. I think `&nbsp` without `;` is creating problem. How can `&nbsp` be removed ?

Comment: Are the characters already coming to you double escaped like that? If you can, the best choice is to start with good data.

Comment: Yes. Characters are like that only. I have no other option to work with it. Is there any method to kill those unicode chars `&nbsp` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the stage of processing in which you want to remove your nonbreaking space, it can be quite easy. For instance when you process the HTML fragment you provided you can just remove the string "&nbsp" from the text elements:

```
s = """your HTML"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
texts = soup.find_all(text=True)
for t in texts:
   newtext = t.replace("&nbsp", "")
   t.replace_with(newtext)
```

Comment: still `replace` is the only way to handle this problem? Is there any other cleaner inbuilt way?

Comment: @Mohamed Thasin , Just try my lxml solution below.

Answer (score 12):

**lxml.html** may be a more suitable library for you, which will replace the "**&nbsp**" and other HTML Tags into the correct characters.

```
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.clean
html = """your HTML"""
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(style=True)
doc = cleaner.clean_html(doc)
text = doc.text_content()
```